# r unable to download file from server

Tags: r, curl, download

I am trying to download a pdf file that is stored in an internal server.

The url for this file is like this below

```
file_location <- "file://dory.lisa.org/research/data/test.pdf"
```

I tried downloading this file using the download.file option

```
download.file(file_location, "test.pdf",method='curl')
```

and i am getting an error.

```
curl: (37) Couldn't open file /research/data/test.pdf
Warning message:
In download.file(file_location, "test.pdf", method = "curl") :
  download had nonzero exit status
```

I tried

```
url <- ('http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf')
download.file(url, 'introductionToR.pdf')
```

And i have no problem downloading this file, but somehow it shows an error when I try to use the same approach to download a file on my server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the file does not exist at that location on your local drive. When I executed the  couple of lines that downloaded from CRAN I get a pdf file in my User directory/folder. I then get success with this code:

```
url <- ('file://~/introductionToR.pdf')
download.file(url, 'NewintroductionToR.pdf')
```

Comment: when I do a (Shift+click) on the url i get a message saying file does not exsist, but when i copy paste the same link in a web browser the pdf file opens without any error, this might be a case where the actual url is something else